# PostGIS: Aggregate small raster to larger raster

Tags: raster, postgis, postgresql, aggregation

I am just getting into rasters in PostGIS and I have stumbled across a problem I can't solve:
Given one large raster A (e.g. pixel size 5km x 5km) and one smaller raster B (e.g. 1km x 1km) which might not be aligned in any way - how do I create a new raster with pixels from raster A (size, position) having the mean of the values of all Pixels in B intersecting the pixel in A as values.
I have come across ST_Union which looks similar but doesn't quite seem to do the job and I don't yet understand ST_MapAlgebra enough to see if it's useful here.

Can anyone help me out with this one?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at ST_GlobalRasterUnion() in the PostGIS Addons. You can do:

```
SELECT ST_GlobalRasterUnion('public', 'raster_table_B', 'rast', 'AREA_WEIGHTED_MEAN_OF_RASTER_VALUES') rast;
```